# Ion-slides with auto play in Ionic3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ion-slides on my home page, but it is not working with autoplay.

Ionic code:

```
    <ion-slides autoplay=300>
      <ion-slide  *ngFor = "let banners of bannersImage">
        <img src={{banners.image}}>
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasAttribute' of undefined
    at autoplay (main.js:43827)
    at startAutoplay (main.js:43870)
    at initSwiper (main.js:43816)
    at Slides._initSlides (main.js:55290)
    at main.js:55311`enter code here`
```

Comment: `*ngFor` is a single word

Comment: yes  ngfor is single word  we are using

Comment: this is working for me - 1) html: `<ion-slides [autoplay]="autoPlay"><ion-slide></ion-slide></ion-slides>` 2) ts: `this.autoPlay = 3000`
let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file.ts

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {  setTimeout(()=>{
         if(this.topProducts && this.topProducts.length > 0){
            this.slides.freeMode = true;
              this.slides.autoplay = 2000;
              this.slides.speed = 500;
              this.slides.loop = true;
              this.slides.startAutoplay()
          }

          },1000)
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

I have the solution:
Do like this

```
<ion-slides *ngIf="slideData && slideData.length" autoplay="5000" class="slideroption" pager="true"   loop="true" speed="300">
      <ion-slide   *ngFor="let slide of slideData">
                <img src="{{slide.imag}}" />
          </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thanks! *ngIf="slideData && slideData.length" is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the *""* in the autoplay attribute, it should be like this:

```
<ion-slides autoplay="300">
  <ion-slide *ngFor="let banners of bannersImage">
    <img [src]="banners.image">
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Btw, when using attributes, it'd be better to use attribute binding instead of interpolation:

`[src]="banners.image"` instead of `src={{banners.image}}`.